# Homepage Automatic horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll

When people enter my website I want to let my homepage scroll horizontal automatically at slow speed. Like a slow slide show.
Does anyone know how to do this? Could not find an answer anywhere.
This is the website:
[website](http://zachtaardig.nl/)

Comment: You have to make a sliding mechanism. I don't think, it is possible. But you can use jQuery to slide elements

Answer (score 0):

You can [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) [scrollLeft](http://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/) property using jQuery like this:

```
jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollLeft: document.body.scrollWidth}, 8000);
```